# C - Read lines from file with float seperated by comma

Tags: c

Let's Say I have a file with Floats seperated by comma like this:

```
-5.5753,7.8474,4.1311
-6.4047,10.7159,4.8474
7.4603,-8.5214,-8.0286
10.5086,-6.1559,-7.0605
...
```

And I don't previously know how many floats are in each line.
Is there a good way to read them one after the other?

I tried something like:

```
fscanf(data, "%lf", &num);
```

But it could only read the first number.

Thanks!

Comment: Split the line by the commas and parse each float individually. A combination of `fgets`, `strtok` and `sscanf` should work.

Comment: Why don't you check how many floats / how many commas you have on each line? Assuming that number is uniform, you only need to check the first line...

Comment: You could do worse than calling `fscanf(data, "%lf,", &num)` in a loop, for as long as `fscanf` returns 1.  (That ain't perfect, and the way it handles the lack of commas at the end of lines is dodgy, but as I say, you could do worse.)

Comment: @SteveSummit worked like a charm !

Comment: Did you want to read the whole file or each line of numbers separately?

Comment: Read entire line into a buffer with `fgets()` and then parse the needed information from the buffer with either `sscanf()` (utilizing `"%n"`) or `strtok()` (or a combination of `scrspn()` and `strcspn()`) or simply walk a pair of pointers down the buffer searching for `','` and then converting what comes before each one (or `'\n'`) That way you can handle any number of floats per-line. You cannot use `fscanf()` because `"%lf"` ignores leading whitespace and `'\n'` is whitespace so the end of line is meaningless there.

Comment: `fscanf(data, "%lf", &num);` should at least read the first number as long as `num` is defined as a `double` and the input file contents is exactly what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about line endings, you can read each number with `scanf()`, discarding any trailing `,`, using the conversion specifier `"%lf,"`:

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double num, sum = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    while (scanf("%lf,", &num) == 1) {
        sum += num;
        n++;
    }
    printf("sum=%f, avg=%f\n", sum, sum / n);
    return 0;
}
```